# When must an employer issue a T4A?

Tags: income-tax, canada

I've worked for some companies as a contractor where they have given me no tax slips or pay stubs of any kind. Is this legal? When must a company issue a T4A? I've heard some do it if you earned more than $500 that year. I do not have my own company and work as a sole proprietor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are a contractor, then I presume you are billing them for services rendered, and no T4/T4A is due to you.  That means you are self employed.

You will need to declare all earnings as self employed income.  However, you can deduct expenses incurred to earn that income.

This is complex, and I suggest you consult a tax professional.